# Powershell script to remove the first and the last double quotes from each line of a csv file

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I want to remove the first and the last double quotes of each line from a csv input file and save the output in the same input file,with ucs-le bom encoding using powershell

The sample csv dataset is (input.csv):

```
"1","2","3"
```

The output csv(input.csv):

```
1","2","3
```

I have used

```
$csv = 'input.csv'
(Get-Content $csv) -replace '(?m)"([^,]*?)"(?=,|$)', '$1' |
    Set-Content $csv
```

but it removes the double quotes from the first and the last element.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: Added  @AbrahamZinala

Comment: `(Get-Content .\in.txt ) -replace '^"' -replace '"$' | Set-Content -Encoding 'unicode' -Path '.\out.txt'`

Comment: the `.Trim()` method will trim from BOTH ends of a string. this >>> `'"1","2","3"'.Trim('"') ` <<< gives this >>> `1","2","3` <<<